# grep NOT maching exact string

Tags: grep

I have a file

```
1 IF 9/1 Joe
2 IF 9/1 Marry
3 IF 9/12 Larry 
4 IF 9/15 Page
```

And I want to print only those lines that doesn't mach `IF 9/1` using `grep`.  I know that I could do that using

```
grep -Fvx 'IF 9/1' file.txt
```

but for some reasons I don't get expected results.

Comment: Add your expected result to your question.

Answer (score 2):

`-x` cause `grep` to match the whole line. You need:

```
grep -Fv 'IF 9/1[^[:alnum:]_]' file
```

Comment: Thanks, but I jus updated my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `9/1` will also match `9/12`. So, use this:

```
grep -Fv 'IF 9/1 ' file.txt
```

Also, don't use `x` option. It selects only those matches that exactly match the whole  line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you said `grep`, but often `awk` solutions look less cryptic and are more straightforward if boolean conditions are involved:

```
awk '!($2=="IF" && $3=="9/1")' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions):

```
$ grep -P 'IF 9/1(?! )' file.txt 
3 IF 9/12 Larry 
4 IF 9/15 Page
```

`(?! )` is the zero width negative lookahead pattern that ensures that there is no space after `IF 9/1` i.e. at least one character other than space follows it. This will get you the desired result.